# Plot using arulesViz the output of arulesSequences? Or, a way to coerce an object of class sequencerules into rules? (arulesSequence, R)

Tags: r, data-mining, sequential, arules

Is there  a way to use arulesViz with ruleInduction output from arulesSequences? Or is there a way to coerce/cast the sequence rules output (of class sequencerules) to class rules, so I can use arulesViz?

Objective: I am interested in playing with some visualization options reviewed in this paper, particularly the "graph" options (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesViz/vignettes/arulesViz.pdf).

Typically you would use arulesViz on "rules" derived from arules, like so (from the vignette):

```
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.001, confidence=0.5))
plot(x, method = NULL, measure = "support", shading = "lift",
+ interactive = FALSE, data = NULL, control = NULL, ...)
```

But I want to use it on the output of cspade + ruleInduction:

```
s1                <- cspade(trans, parameter = list(support = 0.001,maxlen=3,maxgap=10), control = list(verbose = TRUE,numpart=1))
summary(s1)
s1_df             <- as(s1, "data.frame")
r1                <- ruleInduction(s1, confidence = 0.05, control = list(verbose = TRUE))
r1.subset.rule    <- subset(r1, rhs(r1) %in% c("9990") & lift>2 & !lhs(r1) %in% c("300","301","412","4033","4043"))
plot(r1.subset.rule,method="graph",control=list(alpha=1))

Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

Is there a way to do this? I currently get the above error. Note, this is similar to this question: [Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833028/error-in-as-doubley-cannot-coerce-type-s4-to-vector-of-type-double) but the solution proposed there (make sure you have arulesViz loaded) doesn't work/is not the problem.

Thank you for the help!

If you feel that this is not an appropriate question, please leave me feedback/comments -- I tried researching this for many hours before posting here, and am a somewhat new user: Would be happy to hear how this can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this was a conceptual misunderstanding on my part. I ended up contacting the original author of the package (thank you for responding! Leaving your name out in case you'd prefer not to be mentioned) and that cured my tunnel vision.

sequenceRules and rules, even though they look very similar when you you run inspect() on them, are very different classes. The plot command in arulesViz can handle rules, but not sequencerules. While I'm sure I don't understand all the differences, here are a couple:

1. sequenceRules allows repeated elements, rules (most likely) does not
2. sequenceRules could have {A,B} -> {C} and {B,A} -> {D}. Since order doesnt matter for "rules" and arulesViz expects rules, arulesViz likely won't know what to do with this type of input.

Anyway -- I did find another poster in the world wide web who had a similar question, so posting my understanding here hoping it'll help someone out there.

As I said in my question, if you feel my answer (and/or question) should be improved, please leave me feedback in the form of comments! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It may bepointless, but as I am gaining understanding of arulesSequence, I think you can improve your representation. 
(A,B) and (B,A) are the same itemset. And{(A),(B)} and {(B),(A)} are two different sequence. In short : no order within an itemset but order matters in a sequence. So {(A,B),(A),(C,D)} is the same sequence as {(B,A),(A),(D,C)} but differs from {(A),(A,B),C,D)}. 
I think this is why arulesViz, as you said, wouldn't know what to do. Thank you for your question which herlped me understand those packages.