# Self-authored package: load plot method for spatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, package, spatial

I'm writing my own R package and would like to plot a `spatialPolygonsDataFrame` object. If I were writing it as a script I would simply load the necessary packages (`maptools`, `rgdal`, and `rgeos`) with `library()` and plot with `plot(x)`.

When writing a package to build using `library()` [is not advised](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html), instead it is usual to load the package by adding it to `Imports:` in the `NAMESPACE`. If I do this I receive the following error:

> Error in as.double(y) : 
>     cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

This is is [corrected by loading the `maptools` package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436698/3022126) with `library()` if writing a script.

I know you can load individual methods with `ImportMethodsFrom` in the `NAMESPACE` so have tried to import a plot method from `maptools` using this approach but have had no luck. When I looked in the `NAMESPACE` of the `maptools` package I couldn't find a plot method exported. I've seen there is a `plot.Spatial` function which I have tried to import to my `NAMESPACE` without success:

> No methods found in "maptools" for requests: plot.Spatial

Finally, I have tried adding `maptools` to `Depends:` instead of `Imports:` in my `NAMESPACE` and this does work. Is this the canonical way to do this? It seems overkill to attach a whole package for one method (plus I don't know what functions have been masked, etc.). What is the best way to load the necessary tools to plot maps within a self-authored function?

Edit 1: In response to @Hack-R's question, I don't know if plot.Spatial is the only method I need, or even if it's the correct one. It's my educated guess that this will enable me to plot `spatial` objects.

Comment: Let's try to be more specific so that this can be reproduced. Was `plot.Spatial` the only method you're trying to import or was there something else?

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R I'm not sure if it's the only method I need (or even if it's correct); it's just my guess as a starting point. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mdsumner's answer pointed me in the right direction and was a useful discussion in its own right.

The answer to my specific query to plot `spatialPolygonsDataFrame` objects was to add `sp` to `Imports:` and call `sp::plot()`

Answer (score 5):

`plot.Spatial` is *internal* and is in `sp` and not maptools, which I think is the answer here.  You are looking at the wrong package.

As discussed in the comments, you can simply use `sp::plot`.

For developing a package, there's a bit more to it.

If you import the methods for `plot` so that your functions can use it *internally*, but it won't be available to users unless they `library(sp)`.  You could re-export it, so your users don't have to attach `sp` - but you'll need to document it and perhaps explain why, and also check there's no issues if sp is attached.

This is a bit of a challenging topic that is well explained here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html  I was pretty comfortable with namespaces but only recently realized you could re-export a function that you import from another - so you could provide sp's plot.Spatial without Depends: sp.

I override the print methods for Spatial in a package I use, and that in in turn overrides the overrides that `raster` provides - there's no stopping you doing this, it's a matter of managing the user expectations and hopefully not making things hard/er. You probably don't want to override a generic like `plot` for normal use, it's clearer if you have a `myPlot` that does that specifically, or add your own classes.

It's another level complicated though, since `plot.Spatial` is *internal*, and it's source is used to define an S4 method for plot. You can see the methods with `showMethods("plot")` and then get the internal functions that provide those with `findMethods("plot")[["Spatial#missing"]]` or `findMethods("plot")[["SpatialPolygons#missing"]]`.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful and taught me some things about namespaces and methods I wasn't aware of. I looked at the `sp` package and found `sp::plot()` which I wasn't previously aware of and which does the job without needing `Depends:`. If you care to update your answer I'll accept it.