# What is causing this error message when using the party package for a decision tree plot?

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I am plotting a `decision tree` using the `party` package. When running the `plot(tree)` function, it plots the `decision tree`. However, I want to change the font size of the `node` `labels` and I am using the following codes:

```
tree<-ctree(Attrition~MaritalStatus+Age_group,data=traindf1)
plot(tree)
text(tree, cex = 0.5)
```

When running the last line of code, I get the following error message:

```
Error in as.double(y) : 
   cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

I had a look at this post but it seems to relate to another package:
[Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833028/error-in-as-doubley-cannot-coerce-type-s4-to-vector-of-type-double)

How can I fix this?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use `text` to add/change labels based on a `party` object. The `plot() + text()` syntax is used when plotting `rpart::rpart` dendrograms, perhaps you are confusing two R packages?

Comment: See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.1/topics/text. The function `text` accepts a numeric vector as its first argument i.e. `double`. Your `tree` is probably an S4 object, hence the error. Check the **party** documentation for how to fix this or provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note that you should probably use `partykit` instead of `party`, as the former offers greater flexibility in tuning graphical aspects of the trees. Also be aware that `party` and `partykit` should not be used together as `ctree` objects are different in `partykit` and `party`.**

Neither `partykit::ctree` nor `party::ctree` have a `text` method for adding/changing text labels. Perhaps you came across the `plot + text` syntax when you read about `rpart`, which is an entirely different R package for recursive partitioning/classification with decision trees.

Here is a side-by-side example of both methods

#### `partykit::ctree`

```
library(partykit)
fit <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airquality[complete.cases(airquality), ])
```

[image]

You can change the font size through the `gp` function parameter, e.g.

```
plot(fit, gp = gpar(fontsize = 4))
```

[image]

#### `rpart::rpart`

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Ozone ~ ., data = airquality[complete.cases(airquality), ])
plot(fit)
text(fit)
```

Here you can change the font size through the `cex` parameter in `text`.

[image]