# R: plot: Error in as.double(x): cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r, r-package, r-s4, r-s3

Apologies that this is 6 days after a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75610592/r-plot-package-error-in-as-doubley-cannot-coerce-type-s4-to-vector-of-type), however I suspect the root cause may be different. Another [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833028/error-in-as-doubley-cannot-coerce-type-s4-to-vector-of-type-double) post says to ensure the plotting package is `library`'d but it should be (discussed below) and worked fine until this afternoon.

I have a [package](https://github.com/SimonDedman/gbm.auto) whose [main function](https://github.com/SimonDedman/gbm.auto/blob/master/R/gbm.auto.R) automates the process of boosted regression tree modelling. It's a massive sprawling function that does tons of stuff. Today I made a few small changes, adding a feature to include a random variable. Despite this not appearing to impact a later section about model evaluation in any way, when I run the function now I get the titular error. This comes from the following section:

```
evalmetrics <- c("ROC", "kappa", "prevalence", "TPR", "TNR", "FPR", "FNR", "CCR", "PPP", "NPP", "MCR", "OR")
for (s in evalmetrics) {
 png(filename = paste0("./",names(samples[i]),"/Bin_Eval_", s, ".png"))
 plot(e, s)
 dev.off()}
```

`e` is created by `dismo::evaluate`: `e <- evaluate(p = pres,a = abs)`

And when saved as an rds file it's an S4 object of class ModelEvaluation, which it should be. `dismo::plot` wants:

```
x   Object of class ModelEvaluation
y   Character. Either 'ROC' or a threshold dependent measure such as 'kappa', 'TPR'
```

So everything is 'in order' when it reaches the `plot` line. When I step into the `gbm.auto` function and run it line by line, everything works fine. When I run just that section using the exported `e` file, it works fine. But if I run `gbm.auto` as a function, I get the error. Seemingly `plot` is behaving like `base::plot` not `dismo::plot`. But I don't know why this would suddenly start happening. Nor what I can do about it: I `@import` the whole of the dismo package, and `plot` isn't exported by `dismo` so I can't force it with `dismo::plot`.

My limited understanding of plotting in R is that packages can overrule base/graphics as the sole plotting engine if the object class is something specific, and then they put their own spin on things. But my object class IS that specific thing, it worked for years, and all of a sudden it doesn't... but I can't for the life of me figure out how to debug it further, or fix it.

Any ideas welcome. Pseudo reproducible example: ([drumline](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALvf4MvGn8D0sb_h2X440-Y5BlLsmyos/view?usp=share_link))

```
remotes::install_github("SimonDedman/gbm.auto")
library(gbm.auto)
drumline <- readRDS("2023-03-07_drumline_reefs_DtDropOff.rds")
gbm.auto(samples = as.data.frame(drumline),
         expvar = c("Habitat", "Tide", "Season", "LunarPhase", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Depth_m", "Temperature_C", "Hour", "Yearday", "Month", "DtDropOff"),
         resvar = "CaribbeanReef_CPUE",
         tc = 13,
         lr = list(0.001, 0.0000001),
         bf = 0.9,
         fam1 = "bernoulli",
         smooth = TRUE,
         simp = FALSE,
         savegbm = FALSE,
         BnW = FALSE)
```

Comment: Potentially-relevant warning upon installing your package: "Warning: replacing previous import ‘rgeos::plot’ by ‘graphics::plot’ when loading ‘gbm.auto’"; should you be 'forcing' `rgeos::plot` instead of `dismo::plot` (which doesn't exist)?

Comment: good thinking jared, thanks. I've been somewhat ignoring this warning for a little while but it seems like a good place to start. Turns out that was for something which I've since commented out so I've removed it completely. Notwithstanding it was fine this morning despite this issue.

Comment: Nope, no change with having removed that, sadly. But sharp idea.

Comment: Try either of these: Put dismo in Depends. Get the S4 method directly with `getMethod(plot, c("ModelEvaluation", "character"))`. Get the S4 method directly and specify the namespace with `getMethod(plot, c("ModelEvaluation", "character"), where = asNamespace("dismo"))`. I don't have enough experience with S4 to judge if you are doing something wrong or maybe the dismo maintainer has screwed something up.

Comment: Btw., shouldn't you load your package in the example?

Comment: Thanks Roland. Just added the library() to the repro, whoops! Re: your suggestions: Depends: I have `dismo` in `@imports` so it should be fully available, and all other dismo functions I'm using are just being used 'bare' i.e. without `dismo::`. For the `getMethod` approaches: where are you proposing I do this? I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with `getMethod`. If I just punch that into the console in a fresh session I get the code for `dismo::plot` which seems correct... perhaps I should enter this line to `print` , just before the `plot` code is set to run? Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: "I get the code for dismo::plot " No, you get the code of the S4 method. I think you need to do some reading regarding S4 generics and methods. Using Depends instead of Imports attaches the dependency (similarly to using `library` outside a package).

Comment: Thanks Roland. What's weird is this has worked fine for ages and seemingly only broken since I added 2 scripts which use `graphics::plot`. Now I've removed `importFrom graphics plot` from both of those, it's still failing. If I try in console `usethis::use_package("dismo", type = "Depends")` it warns "Moving 'dismo' from Imports to Depends field in DESCRIPTION. Are you sure you want Depends? Imports is almost always the better choice." I reverted that change, removed the 2 new scripts, pushed to github, redownloaded, & the issue remains. So confused as to why this worked before and now doesn't

Comment: You need to check out an old commit that you _know_ had a working `gbm.auto`, then bisect from there.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting **dismo** in `Depends`. Attaching **dismo** won't change the set of classes and methods available to functions in your package. You will still be restricted to those classes and methods that **dismo** actually exports. (Well, you can access the non-exported method with `plotME <- getMethod("plot", c("ModelEvaluation", "character"), where = asNamespace("dismo")); plotME(...)`, like @Roland suggested, but that will receive frowns from CRAN, since it is a hack to avoid proper namespacing.)

Comment: Thanks both. I think I know where I can go back to. What's strange to me is the bit that I changed that likely caused this behaviour, seems to have nothing at all to do with plot or that object in question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to get things working by adding these lines to **dismo**'s `NAMESPACE` file and re-installing **dismo** from sources:

```r
exportMethods(plot)
exportClasses(ModelEvaluation)
```

And then deleting this line from **gbm.auto**'s `NAMESPACE` file and re-installing **gbm.auto** from sources:

```r
importFrom(graphics, plot)
```

The second step ensures that `plot` resolves to the S4 generic function `dismo::plot` rather than the S3 generic function `graphics::plot`.

In any case, you should *not* be relying on unexported classes or methods from other packages.  You might want to contact `maintainer("dismo")`.

Comment: Thanks so much Mikael. As a generality, do you know if one should import graphics / importFrom graphics functions such as plot? Or do they count the same as base?
Thanks for the factorplot thing - I added that this week while helping a friend and it's still unfinished. I've just commented it out. Once I'm done with this and a few other updates I'd say it's time for a CRAN update! In the meantime I've commented out importing graphics::plot, so hopefully that does the job, about to try now.

Comment: Ok so no joy with just changing things from my end. I'll ask the dismo package maintainer about adding those lines and see what he says. Else I'll work out how to copy them into my package and call em locally. Thanks again!

Comment: The second step really does depend on the first step, since **dismo** won't export an S4 generic function `plot` until it has `exportMethods(plot)` in its `NAMESPACE`. But to answer your first question: yes, do explicitly import from "base" packages other than **base** (i.e., from **stats**, **graphics**, etc.).

Comment: I should add that if the maintainer of **dismo** agrees to submit a new version `x.y.z` with these `NAMESPACE` changes, then you'll want to update your `DESCRIPTION` to use `Imports: dismo (>= x.y.z)`.

Comment: Ooh good thinking, thanks Mikael.

Comment: Robert (added these)[https://github.com/rspatial/dismo/commit/e4cc66f2abaec80a46d40f0afc6f7b06f16c7228], pushing version from `1.3-8` to `1.3-10`. I've tried to include this in my package with `use_dev_package(package = "dismo",type = "Imports",remote = "rspatial")` which puts `rspatial` in `Remotes` in `DESCRIPTION`. I manually increased the version in Imports to `1.3-10`, but I already have `1.3-9` installed (odd since it seemed to be `1.3-8` in that commit). "`document()` says `1.3-9` is already loaded, but `>= 1.3.10` is required". Can I auto install from Github? Thanks!

Comment: @dez93_2000 I think you want `remotes::install_github("rspatial/dismo")`? But you need to wait until **dismo** 1.3-10 is on CRAN before submitting a new version of **gbm.auto** having `Imports: dismo (>= 1.3-10)`. I don't think you need or want `Remotes`, since CRAN doesn't recognize it - it is just for **devtools**.

Comment: Ok great thanks - that seemed to be the case but I wasn't sure if I was missing something. Thanks again for all your assistance on this!